# 'gulp serve' command remove attached javascript file from index.html

Tags: gulp, bower, jhipster

I'm using [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) to generate my Spring Boot + Angular JS application. It uses [Bower](https://bower.io/) to packages managing and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to automate repetable tasks. And I need to add Bootstrap js to my `index.html`. I've done it manually like follow:

`<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

I faced with following problem. After run `gulp serve` command it remove attached definision of Bootstrap js from `index.html`. And I wondering why.

I will attach my `bower.json` and `gulpfile.js`:

```
`{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "sykhivska",
  "appPath": "src/main/webapp/",
  "testPath": "src/test/javascript/spec",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.8",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "angular-cache-buster": "0.4.3",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
    "ngstorage": "0.3.10",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "2.4.3",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "json3": "3.3.2",
    "messageformat": "0.3.1",
    "modernizr": "3.3.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "12.0.4",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.3.0",
    "swagger-ui": "2.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.8"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "angular": {
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "3.1.0"
      }
    },
    "angular-cache-buster": {
      "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.8"
      }
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.0"
  }
}`

// Generated on 2016-12-11 using generator-jhipster 3.12.1
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    del = require('del'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    KarmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if');

var handleErrors = require('./gulp/handle-errors'),
    serve = require('./gulp/serve'),
    util = require('./gulp/utils'),
    copy = require('./gulp/copy'),
    inject = require('./gulp/inject'),
    build = require('./gulp/build');

var config = require('./gulp/config');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([config.dist], { dot: true });
});

gulp.task('copy', ['copy:fonts', 'copy:common']);

gulp.task('copy:fonts', copy.fonts);

gulp.task('copy:common', copy.common);

gulp.task('copy:swagger', copy.swagger);

gulp.task('copy:images', copy.images);

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/images/**')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});


gulp.task('styles', [], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/css')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('inject', function() {
    runSequence('inject:dep', 'inject:app');
});

gulp.task('inject:dep', ['inject:test', 'inject:vendor']);

gulp.task('inject:app', inject.app);

gulp.task('inject:vendor', inject.vendor);

gulp.task('inject:test', inject.test);

gulp.task('inject:troubleshoot', inject.troubleshoot);

gulp.task('assets:prod', ['images', 'styles', 'html', 'copy:swagger', 'copy:images'], build);

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(templateCache({
            module: 'sykhivskaApp',
            root: 'app/',
            moduleSystem: 'IIFE'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:dev', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        name: 'sykhivskaApp',
        constants: {
            VERSION: util.parseVersion(),
            DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: true
        },
        template: config.constantTemplate,
        stream: true
    })
    .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        name: 'sykhivskaApp',
        constants: {
            VERSION: util.parseVersion(),
            DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: false
        },
        template: config.constantTemplate,
        stream: true
    })
    .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

// check app for eslint errors
gulp.task('eslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['gulpfile.js', config.app + 'app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

// check app for eslint errors anf fix some of them
gulp.task('eslint:fix', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint({
            fix: true
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(gulpIf(util.isLintFixed, gulp.dest(config.app + 'app')));
});

gulp.task('test', ['inject:test', 'ngconstant:dev'], function (done) {
    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/' + config.test + 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['install']);
    gulp.watch(['gulpfile.js', 'pom.xml'], ['ngconstant:dev']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/css/**/*.css', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/images/**', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'app/**/*.js', ['inject:app']);
    gulp.watch([config.app + '*.html', config.app + 'app/**', config.app + 'i18n/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['inject:dep', 'ngconstant:dev'], 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot');
});

gulp.task('serve', ['install'], serve);

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'inject:vendor', 'ngconstant:prod'], 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot', 'assets:prod', cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal because gulp injects bower dependencies into your `index.html` based on the `bower.json` file provided by each dependency, As Bootstrap declares `bootstrap.js` in [own bower.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/bower.json#L17-L20) in its `main` property, it should be injected. In your case it's not because in your project's `bower.json` the `main` property is overriden

`"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ]`

So either you add "dist/js/bootstrap.js" to your `override` or you remove completely your bootstrap override from your `bower.json`.